# Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Не могу распарсить json - выдает ошибку

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json', true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState != 4){
        return;
    }

    if (xhr.status == 200){

    }
    else {
        alert('shit happens: ' +  xhr.status + ', ' + xhr.statusText );
    }
}
xhr.send();
xhr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (xhr.status == 200){
  var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // и не раньше
```